# How to resize items in qt layout?

Tags: c++, qt

I am currently starting to play around with qt layouts, and I run into a problem: For example if I use a `VBoxLayout`, then every item gets the same space as the others, e.g. they separate the space equally. But in my case I want to have one item with 90 % space and the other one with 10% space. I already found out that I can use `sizePolicy` for that, but I have not found this if I want to resize layouts in layouts (e.g. if I set a layout and an item in another layout). Thus: how can I resize layouts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specifically for this reason you can use [`QBoxLayout::setStretchFactor`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#setStretchFactor).

This method sets how much space should accomodate each widget or layout in coefficients.

You can pass whether `QWidget` or `QLayout` there.

You can read more about stretch factors [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/layout.html#stretch-factors).

EDIT: Here is a simple example which illustrates how it works:

```
QFrame* f1 = new QFrame;
f1->setFrameStyle(QFrame::Box);
QFrame* f2 = new QFrame;
f2->setFrameStyle(QFrame::Box);
QWidget* w = new QWidget;
QVBoxLayout* l = new QVBoxLayout;
w->setLayout(l);
l->addWidget(f1);
l->addWidget(f2);
l->setStretchFactor(f1, 1);
l->setStretchFactor(f2, 2);
w->show();
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: @arc_lupus Try calling `QWidget::adjustSize` on your widget that contains the layout, or `QBoxLayout::invalidate` on your layout.

Comment: Added an example. It works on startup and when resizing a widget. If it doesn't work for your widget you can try what is suggested by @thuga or at least resize it by code or smth like this.